# operator overloading c++ for non-friend class

Tags: c++

I tried to implement the following function

```
std::string operator+(std::string s, int t);
```

but it doesn't get called if I try

```
std::string s = "abc" + 123;
```

although it gets called if I call

```
operator+("abc", 123);
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: `"abc"` is not a `std::string`.

Comment: `"abc" + 123` is `const char* + int`, so pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Jarod42 my bad, I assumed it would be casted to a string as in the operator+ case

Comment: In c++14 and `std::string_literals`, you may use `"abc"s` to have a `std::string`.

Comment: What do you want this addition to do? If it's converting `123` to a string, and concatenating it to `"abc"` to produce `"abc123"`, then you probably want to just use a `stringstream` instead.

Comment: As @Jarod42 mentioned, the compiler does not perform an implicit user defined conversion to `std::string` as you may have believed (it is allowed to perform at most one such conversion), because the `const char* + int` is a better match, no conversion required.

Answer (score 3):

"abc" is not a `std::string`, but a `const char[]`. You could try:

```
std::string s = std::string("abc") + 123;
```

Or, if you are using C++14,

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::string s = "abc"s + 123;
```

Comment: Upvoted for the C++14 suggestion! You can even say `auto s = "abc"s + 123;`